# js-grid Filter does not render

Tags: javascript, filter, jsgrid

I want to use client-side filtering in jsGrid and have implemented the [same controller as in hidden code](http://js-grid.com/demos/db.js) in the demo page (the db.js file) but I am running into a showstopper: the filter row does not display, even when I added a control field (which I do not want) to toggle it.

My jsGrid initialization code:

```
  function initGrid() {
    dom_accountList.jsGrid( {
        height: 500,
        width: '100%',

        autoload: true,
        filtering: false,
        editing: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,

        pageSize: 25,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        fields: accountList.layout,
        controller: accountList,

        data: accountList.data,

        rowClick: function (arg) {//redacted}
    });

    dom_accountList.jsGrid("option", "filtering", true);
  }
```

Side things you may be tempted to correct:

1. **"You don't need data if you have controller"** - nope, by
   trial-and-error I have found that `loadData` is not called until I include static data.
2. **"But filtering is set to FALSE!"** - I know. Whether true in the definition, missing in the definition or false in the definition and then toggled after rendering (as shown), the fields do not render on screen.

Now, I DO see the HTML, but it's all empty:

```
<tr class="jsgrid-filter-row" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 10px;"></td>
    <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 65px;"></td>
    <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 10px;"></td>
    <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 10px;"></td>
</tr>
```

Shouldn't there be `input` tags inside the TDs?  **Why are they missing?**  That's the crux of it, I think.

In case it matters, here is the controller code as modified from the demo's db.js:

```
  function loadData(filter) {

   return $.grep(this.data, function (item) {
     return (!filter.Account || item.Account.indexOf(filter.Account) > -1)
     && (!filter.AXfer || item.AXfer === filter.AXfer)
     && (!filter.BXfer || item.BXfer === filter.BXfer)
     && (!filter.Name || item.Name.indexOf(filter.Name) > -1)
   });
  };
  function insertItem() {};
  function updateItem() {};
  function deleteItem() {};
```

And here is the field list in accountList.layout:

```
   accountList.layout = [
     {
       name: 'Account',
       title: 'Account',
       width: '10',
     },
     {
       name: 'Name',
       title: 'Name',
       width: '65',
     },
     {
       name: 'AXfer',
       title: 'ATeam',
       width: '10',
     },
     {
       name: 'BXfer',
       title: 'BGood',
       width: '10',
   ];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh jeez, after all that, here's the answer: it is necessary to include the `type` attribute in the field definition:

```
  {
    name: 'Account',
    title: 'Account',
    width: '10',
    type: 'text',
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    title: 'Name',
    width: '65',
    type: 'text',
  },
  {
    name: 'AXfer',
    title: 'ATeam',
    width: '10',
    type: 'text',
  },
  {
    name: 'BXfer',
    title: 'BGood',
    width: '10',
    type: 'text',
  }
```